# Fan running 24 x7 despite Thermostat set to Auto for Fan

Tags: hvac, fans

[image]I have moved into a new condo unit in Toronto and it seems my fancoil keeps running 24x7 despite the thermostat set to Auto for Fan. Even when the temperature is set to a temperature lower than the thermostat temperature on heat, the furnace doesn't run but the fan keeps running. Fan also keeps running when i take the thermostat off the wall. I'm not sure what to do. Is there a way for me to check inside the fan coil unit if the fan is set to manual override always on?

Attached are some pictures of my Honewell thermostat and my 4 pipe fan coil unit.

[image: tHERMOSTAT WIRING]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please remove the redundant photos and crop the others to include only the wiring diagrams. Everything else is just wasted space in the post.

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter or multimeter you can use to check for voltage from the various G terminals to C?

Comment: Red on a g is not the normal setup but we would need to see the connections at the controller , and the one with the contacts and wiring if clear might provide a clue.